# Write to file with Formatter in VSCode

Tags: java, file, formatter

I've read all about **Formatter** and tried so many ways but my **hey.txt** file won't change anyway.

```
public class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("hey.txt");
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        Formatter formatter;
        try {
            formatter = new Formatter(file);
            formatter.format("%d %s", 5345, "fds59fd");
            formatter.flush();
            formatter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("yes");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't problem with your code, It works and you should delete this question.

Comment: Your code is working fine. You need to put the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's because of VSCode. I ran it from cmd and came to answer.